# Dialog with multiple choices and custom view

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-dialog

I'm struggling with this problem for a day now, and I just can't figure out how to solve it.

So, I have an AlertDialog where I want to display a list of items to choose. These items must have multiple text views and so, so I cannot rely on a simple `setMultiChoiceItems()` on builder using default format.

I use my custom ArrayAdapter here, by doing this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Choose details to display");
builder.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(this, 0, items), null);
```

I thought I could use an `OnClickListener` as the second paramtere of `setAdapter` but that closes the dialog after choosing one option.

Trying to fix this I added a `setOnClickListener()` inside my ContactsAdapter when I fetch the row layout, like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {....}
```

This works, but I stop getting the highlight when I click a row, which I really don't want.

Any ideas how to solve this? I know I could use a ListActivity and that would be easy to solve, but I really want to do this in a dialog. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think it'd be easy to do using a `ListActivity`, why not do that and use the dialog theme using `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)` or `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` for the Activity in the application manifest?

If you're targeting Honeycomb or Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 3.0+), it's called `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog)` and `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`.

Comment: Well, first because I never heard about that. I'll try that now and give feedback later :)

Comment: Well it worked, but I have to make the whole view (the ok/cancel buttons) and pass extras from one activity to other. That would be Ok, but it is not as smooth as using an alert, really. At least in my phone :) Not really happy with the solution!

Comment: Not as smooth? Are you reusing views in your `ListView` adapter? If not, that'll probably slow down things, depending on the number of items.

Comment: Yes I'm reusing. I mean even the disposal of the "dialog" isn't as smooth as the default for some reason.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I couldn't be of more help. It was worth a try, I suppose. I've never used such advanced layouts in an AlertDialog.

Comment: Me neither. I'll just see if there's a better answer (using more defaults). If not I accept your answer. Thanks.